# How to create custom searchview in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How to create searchview in Android Studio like this ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q90mX.jpg

Comment: Google it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this, Just change the star image with cross image:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mmc.testproject.TestActivity">

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Fly From:"/>


   <EditText
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:minWidth="100dp"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:drawableEnd="@drawable/star"
       android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Fly to:"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/star"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"/>
</LinearLayout>
```